# How to set the parent li class to active when child li is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following menu structure. When a child `li` is selected, for example "Overview", I would like to have the parent `li` highlighted, in this case "About Us".

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="drop"><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
    <li class="drop"><a href="#" >About Us</a>
      <ul class="drop-down">
        <li class="drop"><a href="#" class="active">Overview</a></li>
        <li class="drop"><a href="#" >Security</a></li>
        <li class="drop"><a href="#" class="active">Expertise</a></li>
        <li class="drop"><a href="#" >Process</a></li>
        <li class="drop"><a href="#" >Platform</a></li>
        <li class="drop"><a href="c#" >Careers</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pathname = window.location.pathname,
        page = pathname.split(/[/ ]+/).pop(),
        menuItems = $('.navbar-nav');
    menuItems.each(function(){
        var mi = $(this),
            miHrefs = mi.attr("href"),
            miParents = mi.parents('li.a');
        if(page == miHrefs) {
            miParents.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How you are adding the active class to the anchor? Would you post the respective code too?

Comment: are you trying to active a menu item after page refresh?

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be helpful, try this:

```
$("li a").on("click", function() {
   $(this).parent().parents("li").css("background-color","red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try:

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="drop"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="drop"><a href="#">About Us</a>
            <ul class="drop-down">
                <li class="drop"><a href="/foo">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li class="drop"><a href="#">Security</a>
                </li>
                <li class="drop"><a href="#">Expertise</a>
                </li>
                <li class="drop"><a href="#">Process</a>
                </li>
                <li class="drop"><a href="#">Platform</a>
                </li>
                <li class="drop"><a href="c#">Careers</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname,
        //page = pathname.split(/[/ ]+/).pop(),
        page = "/foo";
    menuItems = $('.drop-down li a');
    menuItems.each(function () {
        var mi = $(this),
            miHrefs = mi.attr("href"),
            miParents = mi.closest('.drop-down').closest("li").find("a").not(".drop-down li a");
        if (page == miHrefs) {
            //miParents.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');
            miParents.addClass("active");
            mi.addClass("active");
        }
    })
});
```

> [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gs0f6jtv/)

---

`menuItems = $('.navbar-nav');` is targetting your main list, not list-items, so your `.each()` loop was trigger only once.